# Retrieve/get current image from Nextgen gallery db

Tags: mysql, sql, image, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I thought that I can do it using the database where the idea was to get the image from the ngg_gallery_pictures table, where the browser URL is equal to URL of the image in the table.
Then I will get only one image and that's also what I want.
Probably I have some mistake here since I don't have a lot of knowlednge in sql but I would like to find the solution for it anyway..

Please let me know what you think and if you can include the code for mysql, it will be great (it is really short from examples that I saw)

Many thanks!

Comment: You might want to ask this question on wordpress.stackexchange.com, where the wordpress programmers hang out.

Comment: I've already asked. Didn't find a solution for this yet.